# C# switch library using with program paremeters

Tags: c#, parameters, switch-statement, class-library, using-statement

I have a project with two class libraries.
I need to switch between them programatically, with application parameters, something like

```
if(arg == "a")
    using LibraryA;
if(arg == "b")
    using LibraryB;

namespace Project
{
    public class MyClass
    {
    // my code here
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to this? Why not reference both of them?

Comment: Its very tricky one, you reference both the libraries, later on the basis of Argument use it.

Comment: If you're referring to concrete types in your code (rather than interfaces), then the specific types or variables are fixed at compile time. Is there any commonality between these libraries (other than, presumably, namespace and type names)?

Comment: You can't do this. You need make your dynamically loaded classes implement some common interface to and use Assembly.Load() method.

Comment: You can't alter a using statement in code, this is compiled into the dll long before any C# code is executed

Comment: Depending on what you're attempting you may be interested in this: http://mef.codeplex.com/.  The idea of runtime conditions around using statements is a no go.  However if you have two classes with the same name in each library you can use conditions around their declaration & use - but you can't leave any ambiguity as to which may be used as the compiler will block this; for that you'd need the classes to use a common interface.

Comment: @JohnLBevan I think almost any other IoC container would be preferable to MEF as most don't require attributes to be placed on the exported types. We are still yet to establish from the OP whether or not the classes in the two libraries share the same interface - which would be a requirement for a dependency injection approach.

Comment: I need this for some testing purposes. Both Libraries have same methods, with same method names, params and return types. Because i have about 20 classes i need to switch effective, without commenting and uncommenting like this: using a; //using b and than  //using a; using b.

Comment: @Hlavson do you have control over these two libraries? Can you make the classes in them inherit a common interface?

Comment: @MattDavey I have control only over one of these. So there is no simple way with conditions to do this?

Comment: @Hlavson no there's no simple way - but it is still possible. I'm about to write you a fairly long answer... standby!

Comment: The correct way would be to pass an instance of the test class to your class's contructor (generally speaking - depending on how your code works there may be better alternates).  There's some good info on this approach here: http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/singleton.html

Answer (score 1):

If you want to build loose-couple application, i suggest you read more about Dependancy Injection pattern.
This is a nice [article](http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/mtaulty/Prism--Silverlight-Part-1-Taking-Sketched-Code-Towards-Unity), desscribed how to build such design. (First 4 lessons)

Answer (score 0):

This is quite a complex requirement and you'll have to bring together multiple patterns & practices to get through this. I'll try and link off to the relevant principles as I go along.

The first problem to tackle is aligning the two class libraries such that they have a common interface. This is necessary in order to make them interchangeable as you describe. Usually this would be as simple as creating an interface that both objects implement - but you mentioned that you only have control over one of the libraries. In that case you need to utilize the [adapter pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) to coerce the library you don't have control over to implement your common interface.

Say we currently have these two classes in `Library1.dll` and `Library2.dll` (Library1.dll is the one we have control over)...

```
// in Library1.dll
public class Foo
{
    public int DoSomething() { ... }
}

// In Library2.dll
public class Foo
{
    public int DoSomething() { ... }
}
```

First we need to define our common interface. This should reside in a core/shared library...

```
// In Shared.dll
public interface IFoo
{
    int DoSomething();
}
```

Now because we have control over library one, we can easily make it implement the common interface in the usual way...

```
// In Library1.dll
public class Foo : IFoo
{
    public int DoSomething() { ... }
}
```

However because we don't have control over `Library2.dll` we'll need to create an adapter class. The purpose of this class is simply to implement the common interface, and all behaviour is delegated to the real `Library2.Foo`. In effect this allows us to make the `Library2.Foo` object implement our common interface.

```
// In Shared.dll
public class Foo2Adapter : IFoo()
{
    private Library2.Foo _realFoo;

    public Foo2Adapter()
    {
        _realFoo= new Library2.Foo();
    }

    public int DoSomething()
    {
        _realFoo.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

Now we need to modify all of our client code to use the common interface rather than the objects directly. Where before you might have had something like this...

```
if(arg == "a")
    using LibraryA;
if(arg == "b")
    using LibraryB;

namespace Project
{
    public class MyClass
    {
        public void Bar()
        {
            var foo = new Foo();

            foo.DoSomething();
        }
    }
}
```

Now your code should only use the interface...

```
namespace Project
{
    public class MyClass
    {
        public void Bar(IFoo foo)
        {
            foo.DoSomething();
        }
    }
}
```

Now we have a new problem, how do we know which version of `IFoo` to use? Is it `Library1.Foo`, or `Shared.Foo2Wrapper`?

You can use [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) to solve this problem. An inversion of control container will provide objects for you, and you can configure it to provide different kinds of objects based on certain conditions. Here's a psuedocode example using a sytax similar to that used by [StructureMap](http://docs.structuremap.net/) (my personal favourite IoC container)...

```
var container = new IocContainer();

if (arg == "a")
    container.For<IFoo>().Use<Library1.Foo>();

else if (arg == "b")
    container.For<IFoo>().Use<Shared.Foo2Adapter>();

var foo = container.GetInstance<IFoo>();
```

Now when we call `GetInstance<IFoo>()` the IoC container will give us back either a `Library1.Foo` or a `Shared.Foo2Wrapper` depending on how it was configured by the command line. We now need to go through all the places in our client code where we previously had `new Foo()` and replace it with `container.GetInstance<IFoo>()`.

I hope that gets you moving :)

Answer (score -1):

Here's an example of how you can achieve what you're after.

```
using System;
namespace StackOverflowDemo.Applications.TestFrameworkDemo.Data
{

    public interface IDataSource
    {
        string GetTitle(int id);
    }

    public class Database: IDataSource
    {
        public string GetTitle(int id)
        {
            string result;
            //logic to connect to a database and retrieve a value would go here
            switch (id)
            {
                case 1: result = "DB First Title"; break;
                case 2: result = "DB Second Title"; break;
                default: throw new KeyNotFoundException(string.Format("ID '{0}' not found",id));
            }
            return result;
        }

    }
}

using System;
using StackOverflowDemo.Applications.TestFrameworkDemo.Data;
namespace StackOverflowDemo.Applications.TestFrameworkDemo.DataTest
{

    public class DatabaseMock : IDataSource
    {
        public string GetTitle(int id)
        {
            string result;
            switch (id)
            {
                case 1: result = "DBMock First Title"; break;
                case 2: result = "DBMock Second Title"; break;
                default: throw new KeyNotFoundException(string.Format("ID '{0}' not found", id));
            }
            return result;
        }

    }
}


using System;
using StackOverflowDemo.Applications.TestFrameworkDemo.Data;
namespace StackOverflowDemo.Applications.TestFrameworkDemo.Logic
{
    public class SomeBusinessObject
    {
        private IDataSource myData;
        public SomeBusinessObject(IDataSource myData)
        {
            this.myData = myData;
        }
        public void OutputTitle(int id)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(myData.GetTitle(id));
        }
    }
}

using System;
using StackOverflowDemo.Applications.TestFrameworkDemo.Data;
//using StackOverflowDemo.Applications.TestFrameworkDemo.DataTest; //we don't need the using statement if we use the whole path below, which I think relates to your question
using StackOverflowDemo.Applications.TestFrameworkDemo.Logic;
namespace StackOverflowDemo.Applications.TestFrameworkDemo
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IDataSource myData;
#if(DEBUG)
            myData = new StackOverflowDemo.Applications.TestFrameworkDemo.DataTest.DatabaseMock();
#else
            myData = new Database();
#endif
            SomeBusinessObject sbo = new SomeBusinessObject(myData);
            sbo.OutputTitle(1);
            Console.WriteLine("Done");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

More info on mocks is available here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650441.aspx

There's also a load of stuff at Channel9: http://channel9.msdn.com/search?term=test+driven+development

Alternatively you may be interested in this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549175(v=vs.110).aspx.  It allows you to hijack methods of existing objects and replace them with dummy methods.  I've not yet played with this, but it looks promising.